# How to check whether another Recorder is running or not?

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, android-audiorecord

I use [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) API to record audio (WAV) in my app, and it records successfully. But my app behaves strange when i try to record while other recording apps are running in the background.

The [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) API throws exception when attempting to start recording while another recorder is running but the AudioRecord API initializes the recorder instance and doesn't throw any exceptions, so i cant identify whether any recorder instance is running or not.

This scenario has been handled in Samsung S3's default Voice Recorder, when i try to record it says

> " Unable to start new recording. Other applications already recording"

How can i identify whether any other recorder is running or not before my app's recorder starts?

Comment: did you get any idea , how can we do that ?

Comment: @SakiMake yes, i'l post it as answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found solution to this problem

Since the [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) doesn't throw any exceptions unlike [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) API, i have gone for another workaround.

When another recorder instance is running i have found that the [read](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) method returns **0** instead of [ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION) or [ERROR_BAD_VALUE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#ERROR_BAD_VALUE). So if the first read operation returns **0** , i showed an error message as "Recorder cannot be initialized".